# Find all the possible combinations of the numbers in the column of pandas dataframe that sum to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10000 rows..I want to find all the combinations of rows where the values in particular column (Amount) sums to 0.

df=

```
ID_Key          Amount
10               12.4
12               -26.6
13                14.2        
14                15
17                 4.5
18                -9
19                94
20                -6
```

Resultant dataframe is

```
Combinations        Sum
(10,12,13)            0
(14,18,20)            0
```

Below is the code for combination of all the 3 numbers that sum to 0.I have to write combination of 4 numbers and 5 numbers too that sums to 0, but even for 3 numbers, when the dataframe size grows beyond 30,it becomes very slow.How can I reduce the time complexity of the below algorithm

```
from itertools import combinations
lst = [] 
t_counter=0
#all combinations ID_key consisting of length 3
for tuple_nums in set(combinations(df['ID_Key'], 3)):

    if df.shape[0]>2:
        t_counter=t_counter+1
        if df.loc[df['ID_Key'].isin(tuple_nums)].empty==False:
            if df.loc[df['ID_Key'].isin(tuple_nums), 'Amount'].sum()==0:
                lst.append([tuple_nums,df.loc[df['ID_Key'].isin(tuple_nums), 'Amount'].sum()])
                df=df.loc[~df['ID_Key'].isin(tuple_nums)]


    else:
        break



df_final=pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Combinations', 'Sum'])
```

I think one of the issues is in the below code,iterator tuple_nums  traverses through all the possible combinations  `for tuple_nums in set(combinations(df['ID_Key'], 3))`
I am reducing the dataframe size everytime, i get the combination that sums to 0 in this line
`df=df.loc[~df['ID_Key'].isin(tuple_nums)]` but still all the possible combinations will be traversed.How can I reduce the time complexity and make the algorithm faster to process 10000 rows

Comment: This is less of a technical problem than an combinatoric problem, for every new number you have to check if you can create a zero by using all other numbers. Without any optimization you are at n^n time complexity, which basically gets much worse with every additional number.  10 ^10  = 10.000.000.000 possible combinations. So you should propably consider a different approach or describe why you want to do that so maybe another solution is feasible.

Comment: I just need to find the combinations of numbers that will sum up to 0..As u said,it's a problem with exponential complexity...I am trying to come up with an approach to if i can solve it with divide and conquer

Comment: You can read about the: Bin packing problem 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem and look for algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a few lines of code, but computationally it will be pretty heavy.

Let's use `powerset` recipe from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Then use list comprehension like this:

```
[tuple(i) for i in powerset(df.index) if len(i) > 0 and df.loc[list(i), 'Amount'].sum() == 0]
```

Output:

```
[(14, 18, 20)]
```

Note, not sure how you got (10,12,13) from this data given.